# Moment JS Subtract method returns 12 hour difference when there is only zero hour left

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display remaining hours, minutes and seconds to a specific preset time (01:00 PM) from the current time with help of [moment js](http://momentjs.com/).
I am using the following code,

```
var n = new Date();
var end = new Date(n.getFullYear(), n.getMonth(), n.getDate(), 13, 0, 0, 0);
var a = moment(end);
var b = moment(n);
var eta = a.subtract(b).toDate().toLocaleTimeString();
```

It works fine until the remaining hours is greater than zero. For example whenever the time reaches 12:10 PM it should display 0 Hours and 40 Minutes remaining, instead show 12 hours and 40 minutes remaining.

How to get this fixed?

Comment: The problem seems to me to be `toLocaleTimeString()` which formats the time to 12-hour conventions and in 12-hour conventions 0 is interpreted as 12 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `toLocaleTimeString()` because it displays the time of a date, so, as Trunst said in his comment, it will display 12 instead of 0 in case of a 12-hour format.

You can use the [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function of `momentjs` to force it to 24-hours format:

```
var eta = a.subtract(b).format("H:mm:ss");
```

Check a [**demo there**](http://jsfiddle.net/fssk7onb/2/) which displays a countdown to your ETA

Note the use of [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) instead of `substract`, see Matt Johnson's comment for the explanations.

---

Note that if you wan to display an ETA greater than 24h, you will have to use the [duration object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) of `momentjs`.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a good approach.  `subtract` is for removing some amount of elapsed time from a moment object to get an earlier moment object.  The correct function to get the difference between two moments is `diff`.  See the question I marked as duplicate and the accepted answer for how to format the output.

Comment: thanks to all for the valuable informations

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson, I edited my example to reflect your comment.