# calculate time difference in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, time

I am new to nodejs, and I am trying to get the difference between 2 times, but I get a different value.
here is my code :

```
         var now = moment(Suivi.FI);
         var then = moment(Suivi.DI);
         var TA = moment(moment.duration(then.diff(now))).format("hh:mm");
```

as a result i get:

```
sql": "Insert into suivi(date, equipement, project, shift, description, Action, user, DA, DI, FI,TA) values('','','','','','','','','','','12:00')"
```

I tried to test with a simple date but I got the same value.
what am I missing? what should I do.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment JS Subtract method returns 12 hour difference when there is only zero hour left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998399/moment-js-subtract-method-returns-12-hour-difference-when-there-is-only-zero-hou)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.format("hh:mm")`

for simple time differnce:

`var TA = now.diff(then);`

this will give you more flexibility for formating (see [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)):

`var TA = moment.duration(now.diff(then));`

Comment: i got the error  TypeError: moment.duration(...).format is not a function

Comment: which version of moment.js are you using?

Comment: i use moment@2.24.0

Comment: i updated the comment, check it out, now it needs to work for sure, if not problem is in the Suivi

Comment: it gave me the same error .
NB : this is the form of the Suivi....
DA: "02:03"
DI: "03:04"
FI: "04:05"
they don't contain the day or the year just the time